# Improving performance of YouTube app

Tags: performance, youtube

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (a.k.a. p4, P7500), running Android 4.2.2 rooted (latest CyanogenMod nightly build: 10.1-20131208-NIGHTLY-p4) and YouTube v5.3.28.

Does anyone have an idea how to improve the performance of the video playback?

What I'm experiencing is a lot of stutter: videos often only show a few frames per second (the audio seems to get priority and plays fluidly). Sometimes videos pause for a few seconds at a time.
I'm testing with preloaded, fully cached videos, so it's not a problem of network connection. Killing background tasks helps a little bit when it's really bad, but doesn't fix the problem entirely.

Now I know this isn't exactly a high-performance device, but when playing them with MX Player, all 720p videos are playing absolutely fluidly without a single stutter. This also includes the exact same videos that stutter in the YT app after downloading them and playing them with MX Player. So the device is *capable* of playing back those videos perfectly fine.

Any ideas what I could try to increase the YouTube app's performance?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the CM build. YT should be smooth on that device, but maybe CM has broken the video decoder drivers or Neon.

Comment: @DanHulme FWIW, it's been like that at least since the latest iteration of the YT app, for a year or so. But yeah, this device is not exactly a primary target of CM ('nightlies' are actually more 'monthlies').
From what I understand, MX Player's 'hardware' playback mode should also use the OS video decoder drivers, so I'm surprised that it performs better.

Comment: I've seen this same issue on other devices with CyanogenMod.  The video within the YouTube app is choppy and laggy, but the video from youtube.com looks just fine.  A solution is most welcome.

Comment: FYI, I've since then upgraded to a Nameless-based build of Android 4.4 and still experience mostly the same effect. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the OS (H.264-)codec the YT app is using, as opposed to the apparently better optimized (mplayer-based or ffmpeg-based, I assume) codec that MX Player is using.

Comment: Try installing Adobe Flash Player android app. It integrates with the browser and system to eventually improve the overall performance for audio/video playback. Many sites and apps can run slow due to the low version of html and low internal storage for which Adobe Flash Player keeps the cpu cool and lets the app take less space for RAM and ROM. And as a result the performance of device can be improved. Its worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

The YouTube app has been and continues to be a laggy little dingleberry. Here are a few things to try:

1. Is there the same level of lag when you try to load the video from youtube.com?
2. Have you tried an alternative YouTube app like [Viral](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Mata.YTplayer)?
3. When updating to the latest nightly, do you clear your Dalvik cache?

Comment: I haven't tried loading youtube.com in a mobile browser yet. I did give Viral a quick try: the performance wasn't quite at the level of MX Player, but it seems to be a lot less laggy than the official app.
Yes, I have had this problem since about a year and the Dalvik cache has been cleared multiple times since then (including right before posting this).